# prints all the odd numbers from 1 to 1000 PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I print all ODD numbers from 1 to 1000 using PHP.

I understand that I need to use the % modulo but I am wondering how can incorporate it.

Here's my codes so far:

```
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){
            if($i%1000){

            }
        }
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You *can* use the the modulus operator but you don't *have* to. There are other ways to do this which are simpler. It doesn't look like you've tried too hard to solve this, though.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the modulo operator does? Your use of $i%1000 indicates that you do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use modulo (find the remainder after division of `$i` by `2`):

```
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){
    if($i%2 == 1){// if the remainder after division `$i` by 2 is 1
        echo $i,"<br/>";// if odd, echo it out and then echo newline for better readability
    }
}
```

Or using array:

```
$a = range(1,1000);
array_walk($a,function($v){if($v%2){echo$v,"<br/>";}});
```

Or without modulo, starting from 1 and incrementing by 2:

```
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i+=2){
    echo $i,"<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I don't know which part - what is modulo, or `for` loop, or `echo`?

Comment: if($i%2 == 1){
        echo $i,"<br/>";// if odd, echo it out and then echo newline for better readability
    }
}

Comment: How does modulo works lets say 1/2 = 0.5 the remainder is 5 why equate it with 1? Can you give me an explanation how does it really works. Sorry slow here.

Comment: it is modulo, not division - 1%2 gives 0 of 2's and 1 remainder equal to 1. 5%2 gives two 2's plus one remainder equal to 1. So all odd numbers have modulo %2 equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sheer h*** of providing an answer using a chain of Generators (and without using modulo at all)

```
$isOdd = function ($value) {
    return $value & 1;
};

function filteredNumbers(Callable $filter) {
    $i = 1;
    do {
        if (call_user_func($filter, $i)) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } while ($i++ <= PHP_INT_MAX);
}


function filteredCountLimit(Traversable $filter, $limit) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($filter as $value) {
        if (++$counter > $limit) {
            break;
        }
        yield $value;
    }
}

$odds = filteredNumbers($isOdd);
foreach(filteredCountLimit($odds, 1000) as $odd) {
    echo $odd, PHP_EOL;
}
```

requires PHP >= 5.5